# Powershell Doesn't Let Me Make Changes in Settings

Tags: python, powershell, operating-system, settings, taskbar

I was trying to manipulate the windows settings using the powershell. Below is the python code with which I try using powershell-commands to disable the taskbar (the automatically hide/show setting in this case) programatically.

```
import subprocess

def change_taskbar_visibility():
    powershell_commands = [
        '$regKeyPath = "HKCU:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\StuckRects3"',
        '$regValueName = "Settings"',
        '$currentSettings = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKeyPath -Name $regValueName',
        '$currentSettings.Settings[8] = 2',
        'Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKeyPath -Name $regValueName -Value $currentSettings.Settings',
        'Stop-Process -Name explorer -Force'
    ]

    cmd = ";".join(powershell_commands)

    subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    change_taskbar_visibility()
```

However the taskbar only hides for a couple of seconds until it reappears again, so the changes I've made didn't stay. Do I have to modify my code to make it work or is there somethin in the os I need to change?

Comment: Are you on Windows 11? Then you may need to toggle between values `122` and `123` for settings[8]. Start regedit and navigate to the Settings value. If there it shows `7A` (122) or `7B` (123) you need these values. In Windows 10 that value is either `02` or `03`

Comment: Oh yes, it was 123 on windows 11, thanks a lot!